# The induced-emf formed in a solenoid connected with a battery

Tags: batteries, solenoid, induction

When a solenoid is connected with a battery and then the circuit is switched on, there would be an induced-emf, and after some time, this induced-emf will vanish when the current reaches maximum value, I was excaliming what will happen exactly to this induced emf during the build-up of the current until it reaches its maximum value? I don't understand how would it decrease until it became zero? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I have never understood the "induced-emf" line of thinking. To me, it is easier, and much easier not to get it wrong, from the circuit and equations point of view.

[image: schematic]

I am simplifying the solenoid to be just an inductor. The equation for Circuit 1 is:
$$ V_L = V_1 = L \frac{di}{dt} $$
It tells us right away that the voltage across L must be V1 and never goes to zero. The positive change of current never stops and i goes to infinity. Obviously, this is a bad model.

The obvious improvement to the model (unless the battery is underpowered) is to include the 
ohmic resistance that you want to neglect. That is Circuit 2. The equation:
$$ V_1 = V_L + V_R = L \frac{di}{dt} + R i $$
Initially, i is zero. All of V1 is across L. i increases.
As i increases, voltage drops across R. Voltage across L decreases, rate of i increase slows down.
Eventually, when i reaches the level where R x i = V1. Voltage across L becomes 0.

If you solve for \$V_L\$ and \$i\$, you get something like:
$$ V_L = V_1e^{-\frac{R}{L}t} $$
$$ i = \frac{V_1}{R} (1 - e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}) $$
\$V_L\$ is not the voltage across the solenoid, we need to include the voltage across R for that, the total would then be \$V_1\$.

Answer (score 0):

back EMF is proportional to velocity of plunger, thus current is non-linear.

- Ta is start current (force)
- Tb is motion of plunger (velocity creates BEMF and reduces I)
- T is activation time while Imax= V/DCR of coil

  [image]

Comment: Side question, any way to balpark estimate Kt, Kemf if you know the L and R of the solenoid?  I'm trying to create a LTSpice model that gives a similar waveform to what you are showing, based on https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/ab-025

Comment: They used K_t = 900u ,"The rotor torque in a DC motor is determined by the current through the coils and the torque constant, Kτ. Torque is represented as the voltage V_torque in the mechanical equivalent circuit. The resulting speed of the rotor, ω, is represented by the current in the mechanical circuit."   Falstad also has a DC motor model in the draw Outputs and Inputs menu with these variables. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoyFI.png